# sqlite3.OperationalError: table A has X columns but Y values were supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

Firstly, I've read all similar questions and applied the solutions listed here: [1] [SQLite with Python "Table has X columns but Y were supplied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643509/sqlite-with-python-table-has-x-columns-but-y-were-supplied), [1]["Table has X columns but Y values were supplied" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587112/table-has-x-columns-but-y-values-were-supplied-error), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hgyl.png)[sqlite3.OperationalError: table card_data has 11 columns but 10 values were supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610859/sqlite3-operationalerror-table-card-data-has-11-columns-but-10-values-were-supp), [4][sqlite3.OperationalError: table book has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198481/sqlite3-operationalerror-table-book-has-6-columns-but-5-values-were-supplied), [5][Sqlite3 Table users has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615032/sqlite3-table-users-has-7-columns-but-6-values-were-supplied) Yet, none of them worked out.

I am creating 26 tables succesfully insert data using this:

```
im.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS C_Socket7 (Date_Requested, Time_Requested, Time_Passed, Energy_Consumption, Cumulative_Consumption, Hourly_Consumption, Daily_Consumption, Weekly_Consumption, Monthly_Consumption)""")   
string = """INSERT INTO {} VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')""".format('C_'+tables[7], tstr, dict4DB['timePassed'], dict4DB['Socket7Consp'],DummyConsumptions['Cumulative'], DummyConsumptions['Hourly'], DummyConsumptions['Daily'], DummyConsumptions['Weekly'], DummyConsumptions['Monthly'])
```

and this code:

```
im.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A_Status (Time_Requested, Socket0Status, Socket1Status, Socket2Status, Socket3Status, Socket4Status, Socket5Status, Socket6Status, Socket7Status)""")
string = """INSERT INTO {} VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')""".format('A_'+tables[7], tstr, dict4DB['Socket0Stat'], dict4DB['Socket1Stat'],dict4DB['Socket2Stat'], dict4DB['Socket3Stat'], dict4DB['Socket4Stat'], dict4DB['Socket5Stat'], dict4DB['Socket6Stat'], dict4DB['Socket7Stat'])
```

But when it comes to this table:

```
im.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A_Environment (Date_Requested, Time_Requested, Voltage, Frequency, In_Temperature, In_Humidity, Ext_Temperature, Ext_Humidity, Door_Switch, Door_Relay)""")
string = """INSERT INTO A_Environment(Date_Requested, Time_Requested, Voltage, Frequency, In_Temperature, In_Humidity, Ext_Temperature, Ext_Humidity, Door_Switch, Door_Relay) VALUES ('{}','{}', '{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')""".format(d_str, h_str, dict4DB['Voltage'], dict4DB['Frequency'],dict4DB['InTemp'], dict4DB['InHumidity'], dict4DB['ExtTemp'], dict4DB['ExtHumidity'], dict4DB['DoorSwitch'], dict4DB['DoorRelay'])
```

It gives the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table A_Environment has 10 columns but 9 values were supplied
```

When I check the database using "DB Browser for SQLite", I can't see the column names. When I create columns manually using the interface, I get the same error.

Here is a screenshot how it looks from DB Browser:
[[image]]

It was working fine when the structure was like this:

```
im.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A_Environment (Time_Requested, Voltage, Frequency, In_Temperature, In_Humidity, Ext_Temperature, Ext_Humidity, Door_Switch, Door_Relay)""")

string = """INSERT INTO {} VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')""".format('A_'+tables[6], tstr, dict4DB['Voltage'], dict4DB['Frequency'],dict4DB['InTemp'], dict4DB['InHumidity'], dict4DB['ExtTemp'], dict4DB['ExtHumidity'], dict4DB['DoorSwitch'], dict4DB['DoorRelay'])
```

I've changed 'tstr' with 'd_str' and 'h_str' which I've seperated date and time into different columns.

I've tried these:

1. Created the columns manually. Got the same result.
2. Dropped the table and let it create itself using "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS", it created the table but no columns in it too. Put the columns manually. Did not work.
3. Delete the whole database and let it create itself from scratch. Got the same result.
4. I also change the provided values in .format() function as str(d_str) and str(h_str) did not work as well.
5. I am planning to create a minimum working code snippet to see which value is not being able to read, yet after seeing that the columns are not being created. I thought the problem is not about the data to be written.

I've read the documentation but could not find something I can use.

Here is a screenshot of the tables from "DB Browser for SQLite"
[[image: Here it shows the name of the columns but columns are not created]]

What do you recommend? What should I do?

PS: SQLite is running on Raspberry Pi, Rasbian OS, Python 3.7, SQLite3.

Using

Comment: Never, ever use `.format()` to create SQL statements.

Comment: OK, after solving this problem, I'll look into it but it is working fine with the other tables. Why is this not working? I thought it might be about the rowid but others are the same as well.

Comment: See my answer. Using placeholders correctly is likely to solve this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *never* use `.format()` (or `%` or f-strings) to generate SQL statements. Your issue is possibly (hard to tell since we don't see your input data) stemming from an unescaped value being wrongly interpreted by SQLite - in effect, you're your own SQL injection vulnerability.

[Instead use the placeholder system provided by your database, e.g. like this for Sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders):

```
im.execute(
    """
INSERT INTO
  A_Environment(
    Date_Requested,
    Time_Requested,
    Voltage,
    Frequency,
    In_Temperature,
    In_Humidity,
    Ext_Temperature,
    Ext_Humidity,
    Door_Switch,
    Door_Relay
  )
VALUES
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
""",
    (
        d_str,
        h_str,
        dict4DB["Voltage"],
        dict4DB["Frequency"],
        dict4DB["InTemp"],
        dict4DB["InHumidity"],
        dict4DB["ExtTemp"],
        dict4DB["ExtHumidity"],
        dict4DB["DoorSwitch"],
        dict4DB["DoorRelay"],
    ),
)
```

Comment: OK, I am changing all. I'll try and let you know. Thanks @AKX

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much, man! You saved me from lots of energy and time loss.